# Time or timing?

Tags: verbs, differences, nouns, adjectives, time

Which of these sentences is correct? I'm not sure of the reason why:

1. I think Summer is the best timing to do this
2. I think Summer is the best time to do this

Comment: Context needed.  There are cases where 1 might be appropriate, but in most cases 2 makes more sense.

Comment: more information added now